# What exactly happens when one calls a 'spawn' function?

Tags: erlang, beam

I am trying to understand how BEAM VM works, so there is my question. When one spawns a process in erlang, the result is a PID. Does that mean that a process is suspended until requested process is spawned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to understand how BEAM VM works.

The details are in the free book, ["The Beam Book"](https://github.com/happi/theBeamBook/blob/master/chapters/scheduling.asciidoc).

> Does that mean that a process is suspended until requested process is
>   spawned?

It depends.

> Erlang is a concurrent language. When we say that processes run
>   concurrently we mean that for an outside observer it looks like two
>   processes are executing at the same time.
>
> In a single core system this is achieved by preemptive multitasking.
>   This means that one process will run for a while, and then the
>   scheduler of the virtual machine will suspend it and let another
>   process run.
>
> In a multicore or a distributed system we can achieve true
>   parallelism, that is, two or more processes actually executing at the
>   exact same time. In an SMP enabled emulator the system uses several OS
>   threads to indirectly execute Erlang processes by running one
>   scheduler and emulator per thread. In a system using the default
>   settings for ERTS there will be one thread per enabled core (physical
>   or hyper threaded).

Answer (score 0):

No the processes are independent of one another. Here are the erlang [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html)